# KinematicBody2D not moving at all when testing game

Tags: 2d, godot, gdscript

I'm using godot for the first time, and for some reason the player does not move at all, however it does detect the inputs.

This is the code I wrote (gdscript)

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const UP = Vector2(0,-1)

const GRAVITY = 20
const MAXFALLSPEED = 200
const ACCELERATION = 30
const MAXSPEED = 100

var motion = Vector2()

func _ready():
    pass



func _physics_process(delta):
    
    motion.y += GRAVITY
    if motion.y > MAXFALLSPEED:
        motion.y = MAXFALLSPEED
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("right"):
        motion.x += ACCELERATION
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("left"):
        motion.x -= ACCELERATION
    else:
        motion.x = 0
```

When I test the game, nothing happens at all

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add [`move_and_slide()`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html#class-kinematicbody2d-method-move-and-slide) buckaroo

```
extends KinematicBody2D

const UP = Vector2(0,-1)

const GRAVITY = 20
const MAXFALLSPEED = 200
const ACCELERATION = 30
const MAXSPEED = 100

var motion = Vector2()

func _ready():
    pass


func _physics_process(delta):
    
    motion.y += GRAVITY
    if motion.y > MAXFALLSPEED:
        motion.y = MAXFALLSPEED
    
    # My project settings has "ui_right" & "ui_left" instead of "right" and "left" 

    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"): 
        motion.x += ACCELERATION
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        motion.x -= ACCELERATION
    else:
        motion.x = 0
        
    move_and_slide(motion) #You missed this chad!
```

Also, *It's dangerous to go alone! Take this:* https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/using_kinematic_body_2d.html

Or if you're a lazy reader like me:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ge0RiUx_NzU